# AlertDialog having input field does not show copy for selection

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I am showing a file rename dialog with existing name pre-filled in the `EditText`.

I want to show "Copy Text" option which is not being shown by default when text portion in selected. Please suggest

[image]

following is my existing code.

```
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            input.setText(file.getName());
            input.setTextIsSelectable(true);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Edit File Name")
            .setView(input)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                {
                    String newName = input.getText().toString();
                    String oldPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    String newPath = oldPath.substring(0,oldPath.lastIndexOf("/"));
                    file.renameTo(new File(newPath+"/"+newName));

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Do nothing.
                }
            }).show();
```